# ClearQuest user cleanup/removal

Tags: clearquest

The ClearQuest user (Assignee) drop downs are bloated with users who are no longer at the company. Is there a way to remove their names from the drop down lists without affecting the history of their contributions?

I Googled it, and checked the Rational site...no luck.

Answer (score 0):

We stumbled onto the answer: if a user is marked as inactive, they don’t show up in the Assignee pull down menu.